# How can i make video go full screen on android?

Tags: javascript, html, video-player

How can I make a video go full screen on android, I have tried the code from these place but they dont work on android https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BuaIDNu_pPg http://www.intheloftstudios.com/blog/detecting-html5-video-fullscreen-and-events

I need it to just work on android

Can someone Please help me thank you all help is appreciated

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you post your code??

Comment: if you look at the links is sent you will see in the youtube video my code

Comment: it is just a regular video html5 player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you elaborate what kind of video are we talking about here, and what is the platform that it is on? Are you trying to add a button to the video player to have the ability to render it fullscreen, or is the fullscreen functionality not working right now?

Comment: a button would be fine

Comment: What player are you using?

Comment: html5 video player

Comment: Can you give us the project link to see what the issue might be? All players have controls built-in so that should not be a problem. If you cannot do that, I can suggest checking this link to investigate an Android solution for custom controls: http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/custom-android-media-controller

Comment: but i will give it to you

Comment: https://tvstartup.biz/mng-channel/vpanel/vod-banbo.php?token=3a5bba820316cb1957cb2bb6b09c9674&id=1649

Comment: There is a view issue, but I can see the fullscreen button in the bottom right, and it does go Fullscreen when pressed. You just need to align content properly, and make sure the canvas fits the screen, so that the buttons can be properly seen.

Comment: I can try suggesting to rather than having 

#myvideo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

To make the values smaller, so that it actually does not expand the canvas so that you do not need to scroll. Trying and put 95% values for each, and test then. The button Fullscreen on the top can be removed, as it does nothing.